# Site hacked username, additional info and password changed question?

Tags: php, mysql, htmlpurifier

I was wondering what could of allowed a user to hack my site, they changed my username, personal info and password. Can someone give me some suggestions on what it could have been. I'm using PHP MySQL and HTMLPURIFIER.

Here is the login script.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { // start of submit conditional.
    require_once (MYSQL);

    // Validate the username or email address:
    if (!empty($_POST['login']) && strlen($_POST['login']) <= 255) {
        $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $purifier->purify(strip_tags($_POST['login'])));
    } else if(!empty($_POST['login']) && strlen($_POST['login']) >= 256) {
        $e = FALSE;
        echo '<p>Your username or email address cannot exceed 255 characters!</p>';
    } else {    
        $e = FALSE;
        echo '<p>You forgot to enter your username or email address!</p>';
    }

    // Validate the password:
    if (!empty($_POST['pass']) && strlen($_POST['pass']) <= 255) {
        $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['pass']);
    } else if(!empty($_POST['pass']) && strlen($_POST['pass']) >= 256) {
        $p = FALSE;
        echo '<p>Your password cannot exceed 255 characters!</p>';
    } else {
        $p = FALSE;
        echo '<p>You forgot to enter your password!</p>';
    }

    if(($e != FALSE) && ($p != FALSE)) { // check pass
        $pass_salt = "SELECT users.password, users.salt FROM users JOIN contact_info ON contact_info.user_id = users.user_id WHERE (contact_info.email = '" . $e . "' OR users.username = '" . $e . "') AND users.active IS NULL";
        $ph = mysqli_query($dbc, $pass_salt) or trigger_error("Query: $pass_salt\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ph)){ 
            $password = $row['password'];
            $salt = $row['salt'];
        }

        if(!empty($salt)) {
            $sha512 = hash('sha512', $p . $salt);
        }

        if(!empty($password) == !empty($sha512)){
            $user_pass = TRUE;
        } else {
            $user_pass = FALSE;
        }
    }


    if(isset($user_pass) && ($user_pass == TRUE) && !empty($salt)) { // If everything's OK.
        // Query the database:
        $q = "SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name, users.user_level FROM users JOIN contact_info ON contact_info.user_id = users.user_id WHERE (contact_info.email = '" . $e . "' OR users.username = '" . $e . "') AND users.password = '" . $sha512 . "' AND users.active IS NULL";        
        $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));


        if (@mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // A match was made.

            // Register the values & redirect:
            $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
            // check if user is logged in then update the old login date
            $u = "UPDATE users JOIN contact_info ON contact_info.user_id = users.user_id SET users.last_login = NOW(), users.deletion = 0, users.deletion_date = NULL WHERE (contact_info.email = '" . $e . "' OR users.username = '" . $e . "') AND users.password = '" . $sha512 . "' AND users.active IS NULL"; 
            // save the info to the database
            $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $u);
            mysqli_free_result($r);
            mysqli_close($dbc);

            $url = BASE_URL . 'home/index.php'; // Define the URL:
            header("Location: $url");
            exit(); // Quit the script.

        } else { // No match was made.
            echo '<p>Either your username, email address or password entered do not match those on file or you have not yet activated your account.</p>';
        }

    } else { // If everything wasn't OK.
        echo '<p>Please try again.</p>';
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);

} // end of submit conditional.
?>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code?

Comment: Which code would you like the login script?

Comment: @asaf, that a look at my answer. It argue about the using of SQL Injections and XSS which are the main vulnerabilities, in my honest opinion, you are having. Also it seems you are using PHP5, so PDO suggestion is really a good choice for you.

Comment: "Please do a security audit for me."  -  Um, no thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website Just Got Hacked Question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588323/website-just-got-hacked-question)

Comment: @abelenky, Lame comment really.

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of SQL Injection. That is what came up to my mind first (noticing the use of MySql). To prevent this you have to sanitize users input by using `mysql_real_escape_string()` (different `mysql_escape_string()` which is considered as deprecated). Despite this solution I'd suggest you to use either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (I usually discourage this one) in order to just fix the SQL Injection problem by the usage of [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Then you should be probably aware of XSS (cross-site-scripting) that could have "injected" in your code some sort of malicious Javascript script. You can fix this a little with `htmlspecialchars()` that make HTML tags (such as `<script>`) not considered as HTML tags.

Also take a look at this [Vulnerability list for PHP](http://php.dzone.com/news/php-code-top-ten-security-vuln).

**P.S.**

In order to make your code more readable and "right" I'd suggest you to change `strlen($_POST['login']) >= 256` into `strlen($_POST['login']) > 255` which is the same but makes the reader understand immediately that the real limit is not `256` but `255`.

Comment: HTMLpurifier should of took care of the XSS problem?

Comment: I don't know it, but i think so. I'd bet they used an SQL Injection thought, only really solvable by using PDO instead of Mysqli (or mysqli functions for prepared statements i personally don't like).

Comment: @asaf, Did this answer solved your problem?

Comment: I think `mysql_real_escape_string()` should prevent almost any kind of MySQL injections. Are there any cases that can be used to inject SQL on `mysql_real_escape_string()` but not on PDO? For the record, I recommend using PDO as well, because it makes writing secure queries a lot easier and tidier.

Comment: Quoting here: "In other words, they can trick your program into running multiple, arbitrary SQL statements instead of just the one you wanted. Escaping quotes should prevent this. But using a prepared statement is more thorough." (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742066/why-is-pdo-better-for-escaping-mysql-queries-querystrings-than-mysql-real-escape)

Comment: That's all true, but if all input fields are being escaped before using them in a query, I don't think that's how they got in in this case.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja, Are you providing some more explanation? (Notice that this answer was posted before the actually copy and paste of his code)

Comment: @Charliepiga, I'm not saying your answer is bogus. I'm only commenting on your claim that SQL injection can only be prevented with prepared statements, because I think properly building the query and escaping the values can be just as secure as using prepared statements.

Comment: @Kaivosu, Just a misunderstanding by my side then.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure they can't perform an SQL injection.  This is probably what they did.  This is normally caused from input fields that are executed.  The person doing it just has to type in an SQL command.

You can see details on this [here](http://sqlzoo.net/hack/).

Oh, welcome to StackOverflow.com!  I hope you enjoy the site!

Comment: Is there a way I can see where the hack was executed on my site?

Comment: Agreed this is the most likely exploit, although without more information I cannot be positive about this. Could have been an XSS or XSSRF exploit. As for seeing where it was executed you would have to look through your code and find any injection points.

Comment: Your best bet is by going through your web server's logs.

Comment: shouldn't HTMLpurifier handled that problem?

Comment: And what should I look for when going thru the logs?

Comment: You should make sure all input fields are secure as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the DalexL answer, please check that you have a strong password to connect to your database.

Comment: A weak password can quite likely be the unlocked door that let the hacker in. A brute force attack can crack a short and/or dictionary based password in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this didn't happen to the original poster, but deceptive companies have been known to send "bills" to companies with web sites.  The fine print in the "bills" transferred the domain from the company to the deceptive company.

Here's one example: [Domain Registry of America scam](http://www.ucan.org/blog/blog/scam_alert/domain_registry_of_america_scam)

Answer (score 0):

If you allow users to upload images, you may have been a victim of a GIF exploit. If your server settings aren't secure, viewing a GIF with embedded PHP code in it will execute the code. Check if you can find any .gif.php (or .php.gif) files on your system, they may still be there if the hacker forgot to clean up after himself.

Answer (score 0):

If HTMLPURIFIER is implemented correctly for all db facing inputs then you should evaluate how you are transmitting your logins. Are you pre-hashing before submit on the client side.

I would assume that the reason is there is an input on a form that is unfiltered and it is letting some SQL injected code through.