# Limiting a SQL Select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am connecting to an SQL database in my PHP script and am having trouble with the `LIMIT` command:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM product
    WHERE `category` like \"" . $_GET['category'] . "\" 
    LIMIT 0, 16
");
```

This all works, except that if I only have 10 rows then `$result` contains rows 0~10 and then 0~6 as well.

I am using a a while loop `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` to check if there is a result and then run an action. Is there any way of having it limit the select statement to only show rows 0~10?

Comment: please type sql injection in the search field

Comment: You should NEVER inject unwashed text from "unknown" sources (read: anything from the GET/POST/COOKIE globals) into a SQL query. Either use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on the variable, or use [PDO prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Also, you should avoid using MySQL's non-standard double quote for strings; it does support the proper usage of single quotes, you might as well use standards compliant code if you can.

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem?

Comment: @Dor: The OP is claiming that MySQL is padding the results to make 16 rows when there's only 10 -- the first six are repeated.  I've never seen that behavior, personally...

Comment: @OMG Ponies - it's possible the LIKE statement is returning unexpected results

Comment: @direct00: That's more plausible than what I understand the OP to believe is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product
          WHERE `category` like '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']) . "' LIMIT 0, 10");
```

is it what are you looking for? It will give you ten rows maximally..

Additionally, please read [this article](http://cakarayam.com/php-tutorial-simple-tips-to-prevent-sql-injection/) about SQLi

Comment: * including the appropriate reference to [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), which in my opinion should be part of the answer... :)

Comment: A better idea would be to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) (but I digress).

Comment: Not exactly... I know about the edit timeout. ;) @rfw - Please see my comment below the question. :)

Comment: @rfw: I do not use any prepared statements and I never saw reason why would I do this

Comment: @JaredFarrish: not exactly? what do you think?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742066/why-is-pdo-better-for-escaping-mysql-queries-querystrings-than-mysql-real-escape

Comment: @genesis: It looks prettier (so you don't have to stare at code with concatenations everywhere), and you can more easily see what you're doing. :)

Comment: @rfw: I do not like it because my logs has double size as normal :p. Btw how does it know that it should be int/str?

Comment: @rfw: Not necessarily, Prepared Statements requires an extra round-
trip to the server.

Comment: @Dor: It's a lot more useful if you're doing bulk operations with the same query, I guess.

Comment: @rfw: so in case you're inserting 20000 lines into table, right?

Comment: @genesis: Yes, but I prefer using prepared statements over sanitization of data since it's less human error prone.

Comment: This is what i was already doing, didnt notice i had inserted the data twice. Thanks to everyone for pointing out the security issues in this, i hadn't even considered that.

Comment: "Why you should not be using mysqli::prepare" - http://joshduff.com/270/why-you-should-not-be-using-mysqli-prepare