# mysql_real_escape_string with PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello i am new to PDO so getting confused and getting errors ;) with mysql_real_escape_string ..

can any one help, here is my code

```
if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST)) { 

include ('connection_pdo.php');

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

$source_url= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['source_url']);
$class     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['class']);
$year      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
$date      = time();
$ip        = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$insert = $dbh->prepare("
  INSERT IGNORE INTO school_students_images
            ( folder_name,  image_url,  source_url,  class, year , date , ip )
    VALUES  (:folder_name, :image_url, :source_url, :class, :year, :date, :ip)
");

$a=0;
while ($a<1000){
$a++;
$insert->execute(array(
            'folder_name'=> $name->content, //** geting from other source
            'image_url'  => $link[$a], //** geting from other source
            'source_url' => $source_url,
            'class'      => $class ,
            'year'       => $year ,
            'date'       => $date,
            'ip'         => $ip
            ));
}
```

it not working getting error but if i am using it with-out

```
    $source_url= ($_POST['source_url']);
    $class     = ($_POST['class']);
    $year      = ($_POST['year']);
    $date      = time();
    $ip        = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

it is working ... so i am confused is it safe to POST without mysql_real_escape_string into database? (is PDO giving any security by default ?) or i am doing some mistake in this...
please help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, PDO automatically escapes your data, so you don't need to use `mysql_real_escape_string`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742066/why-is-pdo-better-for-escaping-mysql-queries-querystrings-than-mysql-real-escape), for example.

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_real_escape_string` requires an active `mysql` connection made through a `mysql_connect` call previously... So yes, it won't work.

PDO does that automatically for you anyway

Answer (score 2):

With prepared statements you don't have to escape your variables. The driver will do it for you automatically, depending on the database you are using underneath. Actually you mustn't escape it yourself, since this will double escape it.