# "\r\n\" in alert for jquery ajax html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request that looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
        var UserName = $('#username').val();
        var PassWord = $('#password').val();
        console.log(UserName);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/Login.php',
            dataType: "text",
            data: {
                username: UserName,
                password: PassWord
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                window.location='pages/mainpage.php';
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('Login Error');
                //window.location='../index.php';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and my php is like this

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

if (isset($username)) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM userlist_tbl WHERE username = ? ");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($selected_row['username'] === $username) {
        if ($selected_row['password'] === $password) {
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
            echo "Welcome ".$username;
        }else{
    echo "Password incorrect";
}
    }
}else{
    echo "Username is empty";
}
```

When i dont put anything in username i am expecting that the alert will be `Username is empty` same as when password is empty alert should be `Password incorrect` but i am getting `"\r\n\"` but if put some in username like `John` it will alert `Welcome John"\r\n\"` why is this happening?how to make it alert `Username is empty` when username is empty same with password?any idea is accepted..

Comment: Do you have anything else after those `echo`es ? Try to `die()` or `exit()` after them ..

Comment: tried exit same result but when i try die the alert is only `""` sir @MihaiIorga

Comment: Try using trim to remove whitespace: `alert($.trim(JSON.stringify(data)));`, or better yet, return a JSON object with the message as a value. That way there can be no extra whitespace around the bounds of the response.

Comment: FYI: You are using `mysql_real_escape_string` _in combination_ with prepared statements here, which is of course nonsense. (And you should not be using the `mysql` functions any more in any case; use `mysqli` or PDO instead.)

Comment: ok sir which should i remove?and why is it none sense so i will remove them...@CBroe

Comment: @CBroe i see what you mean from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750377/mysql-real-escape-string-with-pdo-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:** in ajax section, `dataType: "text",`  change to `dataType: "json",`  and server php code is following:  it may work

```
  //put this function top of this page
   ob_start(); 

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
       $json="";
            if (isset($username)) {


       $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM userlist_tbl WHERE username = ? ");
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($selected_row['username'] === $username) {
                if ($selected_row['password'] === $password) {
                    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
                     $json.="Welcome ".$username;
                }else{
            $json.="Password incorrect";
        }
            }
        }else{
             $json.="Username is empty";
        }
   ob_end_clean(); 
   echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I change `isset` to `!empty` fixed the problem

Comment: im sorry it fix everything i just had wrong alert..when i change `isset` to `!empty` it is fixed it behaves like what i want it to.. @RoryMcCrossan what is the difference between `isset` and `!empty`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier sir it did fix the problem i jsut  change `isset` to `!empty` maybe there is a difference between the two that is why it is working now